# Type declaration in linq in lambda syntax

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I insert the type declaration to the lambda syntax?

Compiles:

```
from DataRow row in dataTable.Rows select transformOneRow(row)
```

Does not compile:

```
dataTable.Rows.Select( r => transformOneRow(r))
```

with error 
`'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found`

I see that the query syntax allows for a type; which makes the compiler happy.
How do I insert the type declaration into the lambda syntax?

The ways I have are:

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => transformOneRow(r));
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => transformOneRow(r));
dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => transformOneRow(r)); // Also does filtering on type.
```

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: @shay__ Yes. See the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32220797/521554 below for what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I insert the type declaration into the lambda syntax?

The compiler will transform query syntax to method syntax. If you de-compile your code, you'll see that the emitted IL calls `Enumerable.Cast<T>`:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Data.DataTable..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // dataTable
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // dataTable
IL_0008:  callvirt    System.Data.DataTable.get_Rows
IL_000D:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast <--- This
IL_0012:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_0
IL_0017:  dup         
IL_0018:  brtrue.s    IL_0031
IL_001A:  pop         
IL_001B:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9
IL_0020:  ldftn       UserQuery+<>c.<Main>b__0_0
IL_0026:  newobj      System.Func<System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow>..ctor
IL_002B:  dup         
IL_002C:  stsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_0
IL_0031:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Select
IL_0036:  stloc.1     // result
IL_0037:  ret
```

So, the equivalent would be, as you did, call `Enumerable.Cast<DataRow>` in your query, prior to the `Select` clause.